# Does Yahoo own Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Does Yahoo own Tor? Sorry I am a noob when it comes to Tor and yahoo. I did hear about Firefox and mozilla, but are these owned by Yahoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo does not own Firefox or Mozilla. [Firefox is created by Mozilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) and [Yahoo pays Mozilla to be the default search engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation#Yahoo).

Tor and the Tor Browser are created by [The Tor Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tor_Project,_Inc). The [Tor Browser uses a modified version of Mozilla Firefox as it's base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Tor_Browser).

Neither of them are owned by Yahoo.